# How do I stack blocks and or tables horizontally to create a horizontal navigation menu?

Tags: css, html, navbar, navigationbar

I wanted to make a horizontal navigation bar with three small transparent boxes. The bar would be centred under my page header. I could not get boxes or tables to go horizontal or centre.

I have, as i said tried to do tables, boxes and table-cell. None have worked out so far. I've checked that the width of my  and  aren't interfering with the elements.

Here's the CSS

```
nav{
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
height: 70px;
width: 1200px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

nav ul li{
list-style-type: none;
float: left;
}

li a {
text-decoration: none;
color: white;
line-height: 50px ;
text-align:center;
font-family: Andale Mono, monospace;
font-size: 25px;
display: table-cell;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And here's the HTML:

```
         <nav>
            <ul>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> Home </a>
                    <a href="#"> About </a>
                    <a href="#"> Misc </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nav {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it.

Just make `<ul>` inline-block and replace margin left/right auto in `<nav>` with `text-align:center` will do the trick, since `<ul>` is taking up the entire width of the `<nav>` which makes browser does not know where to center-align it.

```
nav{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.26);
    display: block;
    height: 70px;
    width: 1200px;
    text-align: center;
}

nav ul{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Otherwise, I would also suggest the flexbox solution provided by Esger for cleaner solution.